# What are the best practices or recommendations that will make it easier to access related models in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Organization(models.Model):
    usercustomer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

In the template, to get the user name, I write `{{ organization.customer.user.first_name }}` how can I shorten it?

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    usercustomer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    def get_user_first_name(self):
        return self.usercustomer ].user.first_name
```

I wanted to solve this by writing methods in the model, but it's not so convenient, I want to find a more flexible solution